# Creation of algorithms for web application

Tags: algorithm, web-applications

I'm new to web programming. Where is the best place online can I find examples of algorithms created to solve specific problems ie. reputation system for a user controlled forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my opinion a good introduction to this issue you can fing in this book:

[image]

## Paperback: 336 pages

## Publisher: Yahoo Press; 1 edition (March 16, 2010)

## Language: English

## ISBN-10: 059615979X

## ISBN-13: 978-0596159795

Table of Contents:

Part I. Reputation Defined and Illustrated

1. Reputation Systems Are Everywhere
2. A (Graphical) Grammar for Reputation

Part II. Extended Elements and Applied Examples

3. Building Blocks and Reputation Tips
4. Common Reputation Models
5. Planning Your System’s Design
6. Objects, Inputs, Scope, and Mechanism
7. Displaying Reputation
8. Using Reputation: The Good, The Bad, and the Ugly
9. Application Integration, Testing, and Tuning
10. Case Study: Yahoo! Answers Community Content Moderation

Here you can buy it: [http://www.amazon.com/Building-Reputation-Systems-Randy-Farmer/dp/059615979X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059615979X)

Comment: Thanks, do you know any other general book on algorithms and web programming

Comment: Some good introductional books: http://www.amazon.com/dp/1933988312/   http://www.amazon.com/dp/1933988665/   http://www.amazon.com/dp/1933988665/